# Display json array

Tags: php, json, wordpress, wp-api

I am trying to read an api I have implemented with Wordpress using WP-API V2, I have used several plugins to return the information i need.

The source json [can be found here](http://dev.selectparkhomes.com/wp-json/wp/v2/property?filter[taxonomy]=property-city&filter[term]=fell-view-park).

I need to return `pure_taxonomies->property-status->name`.

I have tried the following but i just get a blank page:

```
foreach($select_api as $p)
{
  echo '
  Status:'.$p->pure_taxonomies->property-status->name.'
  ';
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you want to `return` it or `echo` it?

Comment: I'll write common answer. but what you get in $select_api? Does foreach work?

Comment: Please tell us how $select_api is populated with data from the json.

Comment: it is populated like this: $select_api = json_decode($string); the $string being either a cached file or the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you have json_encoded string, you should decode it with 
json_decode()
I decoded your json and get array with two elements.
Your error is probably because of hyphen **property-status** in name of property. 
You should use curly braces:

```
Status:'.$p->pure_taxonomies->{"property-status"}[0]->name.'
```

**IMPORTANT.**

1. Use curly braces for property names with hyphen
2. Don't forget that in your structure **property-status** is array. That's why I used index 0 to get first element